# How to set set capability for chrome in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to use [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html#setCapability%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method? What parameter should I pass to "capabilityName" and "value"?

```
public void setCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName,java.lang.String value);
```

Answer (score 4):

For Chrome specifically, you can find the capabilities here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities-aka-chromeoptions

There is a more general overview of capabilities on the selenium wiki: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that maximizes the browser window (for chrome). Enable/Disable the second while running it and see the difference.

```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what other arguments can i set like "--start-maximized" ? Please point me to the reference link.

Comment: Ajay - if you read the DesiredCapabilities link I posted above, it points to another link under 'args': http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ Note these are chrome/chromium specific and nothing to do with selenuim. 

FYI, you can achieve a similar effect to "--start-maximized" from selenium by using `driver.maximize_window()`. This is driver/browser independent.